# Perfect-centering characters in a box

Tags: vertical-alignment, inkscape

I have made in Inkscape a page layout with some boxes here and there that should contain a single Kanji character. These Kanji should be horizontally and vertically centered in the box. At the very middle of the boxes I have put a text box whit a dummy latex function name (like \MyBox), then I have exported the layout by using the pdf+latex option.

Here a MWE (XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}

\usepackage[margin=0cm, a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\fontK}[Scale=2.00]{epkyouka.ttf}

\newcommand{\MyBox}{}%


\begin{document}

\def\svgwidth{\paperwidth}

\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\MyBox}{\fontK{一}}
%\renewcommand{\MyBox}{\fontK{日}}
\centerline{\input{layout.pdf_tex}}

\end{document}
```

Layout.pdf_tex:

```
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{595.27558594bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,1.4142857)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{layout.pdf}}%
    \put(0.06949339,1.29607556){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\begin{minipage}{0.05495935\unitlength}\centering \MyBox\end{minipage}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

In order to get, e.g., 日 centered, I had to shift the text box in Inkscape a little bit down, but seems that 一 needs some more down shifting to be centered. I suppose my problem is all about baseline alignment. There is a way to obtain what I need?

**EDIT**

So, as usual I have found a dirty workaround right after I have promoted a bounty for my question :)
Long story short:

```
\renewcommand{\MyBox}{\fontK{一\phantom{日}}}
```

sounds good to me, but still a hack. What's the proper way to proceed?

Comment: I had the same kind of problem recently. In Inkscape when you create your textbox, make sure to actually create a textbox, using click+drag (not simply click). Then in inkscape center-justify your text. Then export to PdF+Latex, compile and it should be centered.

Comment: That's what I do now. The issue is in vertically centering the text. As far as I can see, some kanji have an accentuated shift of the baseline, that I can't figure how to handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with Inkscape. Searching [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes), I found something about the `\raisebox` command:

```
\raisebox{lift}[height][depth]{text}
```

You can use `\height` or `\depth` or `\totalheight` in the first parameters with a constant to precisely set the vertical shift.

For my own usage, I use the following:

```
\newcommand{\inksvcenter}[1]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{#1}}
```

I use it in my Inkscape text : \inksvcenter{\fontK{日}}

and I align the baseline with the vertical middle of the rectangle where I put the text.

Of course, you can adjust the `-0.5` coefficient with a value of your own in order to correctly align your text.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks!